# Uncaught ReferenceError: 'functionName' not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have checked my script tags in my .jsp file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" > "some content here ...." </script>
```

and below in the same .jsp file I have a tag:

```
<body BGCOLOR="white" text="black" link="blue" vlink="red" onLoad="functionName();enableBackButton();">
```

However, in my JavaScript file I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('current').click(function(event){

    function functionName() { ....... }
```

Somehow I keep getting an error in my Chrome console stating:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: functionName is not defined**

Comment: Just FYI jQuery 1.3.1 is **ancient**.

Comment: @pointy, the system is ancient itself. I wish it was all mine haha...

Comment: OK, but be aware that it's likely to have problems with newer browsers, including IE9+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move your `functionName()` out side of `$(document).ready(function(){`

```
function functionName() { ....... }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.current').click(function(event){
        functionName();
    });
});
```

Also, you need to use `.` to target element by class or `#` to target element by `id`

So `$('.current')` will select any element with `class="current"` and `$('#current')` will select an element with `id="current"`

Last note is to update your jQuery version since `1.3.1` is extremely outdated already and it lacks of many helpful and important features which is supported by later versions.

Comment: thanks for the usage of {.} and {#}. I learn new things everyday. :)

Comment: could it be possible to have function functionName { and an ajax call in here} ? In this case having a function that also performs an ajax call when called? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course. Also, you can go through this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call if you intend to return a value from your ajax call

Answer (score 3):

Don't wrap your function in `DOM ready($(document).ready(function(){)` handler.As it is a anonymous  function so your `functionName()` function has `local scope`.So you can  not call it outside the `DOM ready`

Read [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

---

http://api.jquery.com and http://learn.jquery.com

Answer (score 3):

Moving the function would be one way to fix it, but an alternative is to simply call the function from your "ready" handler, or if it really matters that all page content is loaded, from a "load" handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function functionName() {
    // whatever
  }

  functionName();
});
```

Polluting the global namespace unnecessarily is generally a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

`function functionName() {` should defined outside the `$(document).ready(function(){`, like

```
function functionName() {...}
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

If you defined it inside the `document.ready` then it's scope would limit into this function.

Only you can defined when the `functionName()` would call from inside `$(document).ready(` like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function functionName() {...}
      // but in your case below function 
      // is calling from body when its loaded
      functionName(); //from here you can call
    } 
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call functionName in onLoad, the function is not yet in the document.
Try to put the function functionName out.
For instance,

```
<script language="JavaScript" > 

"some content here ...." 

function functionName() {
  your function
}

</script>
```